# Как организовать выбор «мастер» сервера node.js используя Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

Здравствуйте. Задача: при одновременном запуске n'ого количества серверов один из них должен стать генератором сообщений, остальные их обрабатывают. Генератор может быть только один. При "падении" генератора любой из обработчиков его заменяет. Все общение должно происходить через Redis.

Первое что приходит на ум: при запуске все пишут в редис *SETNX generator < ip >*. Затем по таймеру каждый проверяет значение ключа generator и если оно равно своему ip сервер становится генератором.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это классический прием для leader election без непосредственно реализации соответствующих алгоритмов. По факту это просто сервис распределенных блокировок и взятие одной из таких блокировок; обычно для этого используют zookeeper, consul, etcd или аналог - в consul, например, есть понятие *сессии*, которая забирает блокировку и отпускает по желанию или по факту смерти (это выглядит более логичным, чем просто забор отдельных ключей). Необходимо предупредить, что этот метод требует большой осторожности с таймингами, потому что довольно легко как спрыгнуть в состояние прыгающего туда-сюда лидера, так и слишком часто гонять лишние данные по сети (вряд ли это сильно скажется на быстродействии приложения, но когда у меня за полчаса трафик с redis только одними локами составил 2гб - было не очень приятно).